# How do i make my bot to read messages and reply with the code inside?

Tags: javascript, discord

Here is the code for my discord bot. It's basically retyping what the users type. When i type ^speak loveme, " ^ " is my prefix for my bot, it should answer " In your dreams, weirdo." but it does not work it will just type "loveme".

```
if(command === 'speak'){

    if(!args.length){

        return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You didn't type anything, dummy.`)

    }

    else if (args == 'loveme'){

        return message.channel.send("In your dreams, weirdo.");

    }

    message.channel.send(`${args.slice(0).join(' ')}`);

}
```

Comment: Should that be java or javascript?

Comment: But do you want `args[0]=='loveme'`?

Comment: How di you obtain args?

Comment: @dan1st i have tried that and it still wont work

Comment: to obtain is its after " ^speak food and water" the args is " food and water"          
 var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();